# How do I change a specific MDB max-pool-size at runtime on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, message-driven-bean

I'd like to be able to change the max-pool-size value at runtime. Currently I have to modify the xml and restart Glassfish.

Any ideas?

Comment: which xml file are you modifying?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with ['asadmin set'](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-0179/set-1?l=en&a=view).  I do not know the particular name you needto use, though.

Use ["asadmin get '*'"](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-0179/get-1?l=en&a=view) (after you have deployed your MDB) to find the name that you will need to use.

Comment: This let's you change it, but until you restart it doesn't seem to take affect.